# Optimising array addition (y, x, RGBA)

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, optimization, graphics

I have two arrays A, B that are both of the shape (42, 28, 4) where:

```
42 : y_dim
28 : x_dim
4  : RGBA
## I'm on MacBook Air M1 2020 16Gb btw
```

I want to combine these through a similar process to this:

```
def add(A, B):
    X = A.shape[1]
    Y = A.shape[0]
    alpha = A[..., 3] / 255

    B[..., :3] = blend(B[..., :3], A[..., :3], alpha.reshape(Y, X, 1))    

    return B

def blend(c1, c2, alpha):
    return np.asarray((c1 + np.multiply(c2, alpha))/(np.ones(alpha.shape) + alpha), dtype='uint8')
```

But currently this is a bit too slow (~20 ms with 250 images overlayed on top of a base array [1]) for my liking and if you have any ways to improve this (preferably with 8bit alpha support) I'd be happy to know.

[1]:

```
start = time.time()
for obj in l: # len(l) == 250
    _slice = np.index_exp[obj.y * 42:(obj.y+1) * 42, obj.x * 28 : (obj.x+1) * 28, :]
    self.pixels[_slice] = add(obj.array, self.pixels[_slice])

stop = time.time()
>>> stop - start # ~20ms
```

I've semi-tried the following:

```
# cv2.addWeighted() in add()
## doesn't work because it has one alpha for the whole image,
## but I want to have indiviual alpha control for each pixel

B = cv.addWeighted(A, 0.5, B, 0.5, 0)
```

```
# np.vectorize blend() and use in add()
## way too slow because as the docs mention it's basically just a for-loop

B[..., :3] = np.vectorize(blend)(A[..., :3], B[..., :3], A[..., 3] / 255)

# changed blend() to the following
def blend(a, b, alpha):
    if alpha == 0:
        return b
    elif alpha == 1:
        return a
    
    return (b + a * alpha) / (1 + alpha)
```

```
# moved the blend()-stuff to add()
## doesn't combine properly; too dark with alpha

np.multiply(A, alpha.reshape(Y, X, 1)) + np.multiply(B, 1 - alpha.reshape(Y, X, 1))
```

I've also tried some bitwise stuff but my monkey brain can't comprehend it properly. I am on a M1 Mac so if you have any experience with metalcompute and Python please include any thoughts about that!

Any input is welcomed, thanks in advance!

**Answer:** Christoph Rackwitz posted a very elaborate and well constructed answer so if you are curious about similar things check out the accepted commend below.

To add to this I ran Christoph's code on my M1 computer to show the results.

```
2500 calls (numpy)       = 0.0807
2500 calls (other)       = 0.0833
2500 calls (Christoph´s) = 0.0037
```

Comment: I don't see a loop in the first code that needs 'vectorization' .  It just looks like you are modifying `B[...,3]` based on corresponding values in `A`.  And as you found out `np.vectorize` dkes nothing fir you.

Comment: @hpaulj Yeah exactly, I was just trying out different stuff :)

Comment: the usual: try numba. or add your voice to https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/20780 or even implement it -- "a bit too slow", please quantify that and present your method of measurement

Comment: just get the GPU to do it for you. that is its purpose. all you're doing so far is purely CPU time. you aren't doing "array addition", you are alpha-blending. granted, such tiny pictures are hardly worth the effort of uploading them to GPU memory but this is fundamentally a graphics operation.

Comment: this is clearly some type of "tile map" game and you are doing game graphics. you should use the appropriate libraries for this. all that `obj` and `self.pixels` stuff is undefined. you'll need to present a [mre]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, your blending equation looks wrong. Even with `alpha` being 255, you'd only get a 50:50 mix. You'd want something like `B = B * (1-alpha) + A * alpha` or rearranged `B += (A-B) * alpha` but that expression has teeth (integer subtraction will have overflow/underflow).

---

You appear to be drawing "sprites" in a grid on the display of a game. Just use 2D graphics libraries for this, or even 3D (OpenGL?). GPUs are very good at drawing textured quads with transparency. Even without involvement of a GPU, the right library will contain optimized primitives and you don't have to write any of that yourself.

The cost of uploading textures (to GPU memory) is a one-time cost, assuming the sprites don't change appearance. If they change for every frame, that may be noticeable.

---

Since I originally proposed to use [numba](/questions/tagged/numba) and previous answers have only gotten a factor of 2 and then 10 out of it, I'll show a few more points to be aware.

A previous answer proposes a function with this in its inner loop:

```
B[i, j, :3] = (B[i, j, :3] + A[i, j, :3] * alpha[i, j]) / (1 + alpha[i, j])
```

Seems sensible because it treats the entire pixel at once *but* this ***still uses numpy***, which is comparatively slow because it's written to be generic (various dtypes and shapes). Numba has no such requirement. It'll happily generate the specific machine code for this specific situation (uint8, fixed number of dimensions, fixed iterations of inner loop).

If you unroll this one more time, removing the numpy calls from the inner loop, you'll get the ***true speed of numba***:

```
for k in range(3):
    B[i, j, k] = (B[i, j, k] + A[i, j, k] * alpha[i, j]) / (1 + alpha[i, j])
```

Timing results (relative speed important, my computer is old):

```
2500 calls (numpy)    = 0.3845
2500 calls (other)    = 0.5039
2500 calls (mine)     = 0.0901
```

You can keep going, pulling constants out of each loop, in case LLVM (what numba uses) doesn't notice the optimization.

Cache locality plays a huge role as well. Instead of calculating an entire `alpha` array once, just calculate the per-pixel alpha in the second to inner loop:

You should look at the **`dtype`** of `alpha = .../255`, which is **`float64`**. Use float32 instead of float64 because that's usually faster.

```
alpha = A[i, j, 3] * np.float32(1/255)
for k in range(3):
    B[i, j, k] = (B[i, j, k] + A[i, j, k] * alpha) / (1 + alpha)
```

And now let's do integer arithmetic, which is even faster than floating point, and with correct blending:

```
alphai = np.int32(A[i, j, 3]) # uint8 needs to be widened to avoid overflow/underflow
for k in range(3):
    a = A[i, j, k]
    b = B[i, j, k]
    c = (a * alphai + b * (255 - alphai) + 128) >> 8 # fixed point arithmetic, may be off by 1
    B[i, j, k] = c
```

Finally:

```
2500 calls (numpy)    = 0.3904
2500 calls (other)    = 0.5211
2500 calls (mine)     = 0.0118
```

So that's a speedup of 33. And that's on my old computer that doesn't have any of the latest vector instruction sets.

And instead of calling such a function 250 times, you could call it *one* time with all the data. That *may* open up the possibility of **parallelism**. Numba lets you do it, but it's not trivial...

Since your game display is a grid, you can collect all the sprites for each grid cell (ordered of course). Then you can render each cell in parallel.

Comment: Hahaha wow, thank you very much for this! 


I actually was using a graphics library (PIL Image with ImageTk to get a PhotoImage to use with tkinter) but this kind of constricted my freedom a bit in certain areas (e.g. not being able to change the color of an Image easily). So I thought I'd try to have just one array that is made into a PhotoImage where everything is combined from other smaller arrays. But as you correctly mentioned this puts the 'graphics' on the CPU instead of the GPU which isn't ideal. 


Yeah, the blending is probably wrong lol.

Comment: I've added your suggestions and yes - not creating numpy arrays (+ not creating `alpha` array) in a loop and now the performance is ~10x than normal (not ~2x)

Comment: for (game) graphics: PyGame, SDL, maybe even whatever wrappers there are for OpenGL or Direct3D. -- GPUs are good at keeping textures, so the cost of uploading would be a one-time cost.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Yeah, I'm trying to stay away from PyGame as I saw that it had some restrictions on how threading could possibly be used and that is something I might want to do in the future. And there are a lot of things in this game that would benefit from not being too closely tied to an Imaging Library but as you've previously noted this does come with some setbacks :) Again thank you very much for this response, its immensely appreciated!

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Hey, can you send me the source code for this? I've tried it in a couple different implementations but on M1 I'm not seeing anything near 33x faster (instead maybe 3x, which is definitely not bad but it's just peculiar). So if I could test the exakt thing you had I could add it to my post in order to clarify differences between M1 and your computer. Thank you!

Comment: https://gist.github.com/crackwitz/103bb8a9bbd70ab643e732ebf481bce8

Answer (score 1):

Here is [numba](/questions/tagged/numba) version, which is on my computer (AMD 5700x) ~8-10x faster than the original version (I don't have M1 so your results may vary):

```py
@njit
def add_numba(A, B):
    for i in range(A.shape[0]):
        for j in range(A.shape[1]):
            a = A[i, j, 3] / 255
            for k in range(3):
                B[i, j, k] = (B[i, j, k] + A[i, j, k] * a) / (1 + a)

    return B
```

---

Benchmark:

```py
from statistics import median
from timeit import repeat

import numpy as np
from numba import njit


@njit
def add_numba(A, B):
    for i in range(A.shape[0]):
        for j in range(A.shape[1]):
            a = A[i, j, 3] / 255
            for k in range(3):
                B[i, j, k] = (B[i, j, k] + A[i, j, k] * a) / (1 + a)

    return B


def setup_A_B():
    A = np.random.randint(0, 255, size=(42, 28, 4), dtype="uint8")
    B = np.random.randint(0, 255, size=(42, 28, 4), dtype="uint8")
    return A, B


def add(A, B):
    X = A.shape[1]
    Y = A.shape[0]
    alpha = A[..., 3] / 255

    B[..., :3] = blend(B[..., :3], A[..., :3], alpha.reshape(Y, X, 1))

    return B


def blend(c1, c2, alpha):
    return np.asarray(
        (c1 + np.multiply(c2, alpha)) / (np.ones(alpha.shape) + alpha), dtype="uint8"
    )


# assert the result is equal
np.random.seed(42)
A1, B1 = setup_A_B()
A2, B2 = A1.copy(), B1.copy()
assert np.allclose(add(A1, B1), add_numba(A2, B2))


np.random.seed(42)
repeats_normal = repeat(
    "add(A, B)", setup="A, B = setup_A_B()", globals=globals(), number=2500, repeat=10
)

np.random.seed(42)
repeats_numba = repeat(
    "add_numba(A, B)",
    setup="A, B = setup_A_B()",
    globals=globals(),
    number=2500,
    repeat=10,
)

print(f"2500 calls (original) = {median(repeats_normal):.8f}")
print(f"2500 calls (numba)    = {median(repeats_numba):.8f}")
```

Prints:

```
2500 calls (original) = 0.12811599
2500 calls (numba)    = 0.01316734
```

---

EDIT: Added @ChristophRackwitz's suggestions to not create numpy arrays in loop.